# Image Uploader Error

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I'm trying to build a simple image upload but I'm getting an error telling me its an invalid file when I'm trying to upload any image. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    $allowExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "stl");
    $extensions = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/stl"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 21000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowExts))

    {
        if ($_FILES ["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "ERROR: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }

        else{
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"];
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Stores in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
                echo $FILES["file"]["name"] . "already exists. ";
            }
            else{
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "upload/" . $FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $FILES["file"]["name"];
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid File";
        }

?>
```

Here is my adjusted file based on the edits I've made:

```
<?php

$allowExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "stl");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/stl"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 30000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowExts))

{
    if ($_FILES ["file"]["error"] > 0){
    echo "ERROR: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }

    else{
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Stores in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

        if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])){
            echo $FILES["file"]["name"] . "already exists. ";
        }
        else{
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "images/" . $FILES["file"]["name"]);
            echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
    }
}
else{
    echo "Invalid File";
    print_r($_FILES);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Try: `echo $_FILES["file"]["type"];` to see what type of file it is and if it is in your list.

Comment: Show us the result of `print_r($_FILES)`.

Comment: I know the files that I've tried to upload are png and jpg, neither seem to work yet I have them In the list. Using Google Chrome, not IE or Firefox where the other jpg extensions would be needed also.

Comment: @MrCode when I added that in the file Uploaded to 100% then I got this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /../../../../../../upload.php on line 26

Comment: Did you terminate the line with a semicolon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify it a wee bit; 
HTML should look something like this:

```
<form method='POST' action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile"  />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>
```

your PHP, try this instead:

```
<?php
//GRAB IMAGE FROM POST
$pic = $_FILES['userfile'];
$picName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$file_ext =  strtolower(end(explode(".", $picName )));



if($file_ext == "jpg" || $file_ext == "jpeg" || $file_ext == "gif" || $file_ext == "png" ){

    //MAKE SURE YOU HAVE CHMOD 777 THIS DIRECTORY AND DOUBLE CHECK THIS IS THE CORRRECT DIRECTORY!
    $theDirectory = 'upload/theImage.'.$file_ext;

    //MOVE THE FILE TO THIS DIRECTORY
    move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $theDirectory);


}
else{


        echo 'bad file';
}

?>
```

it's a bit of a work around to validate the file, but it does the trick. Make sure you name the php file `upload.php` or whatever you want, just make sure you change the `form` on the html to match. Make sure you chmod the folder `"upload"` to 777. Doing it this way should work indefinitely. I always find it's best to get it to work, then go back and work on security. For instance, you should use the GD libraries to validate it's a legit image by doing something like this(this bit may need to be adjusted):

```
//MAKE IT A JPEG

$theDirectoryTwo = 'upload/theImageValidated.jpg';
$theRawImage = file_get_contents($theDirectory);
$theRawImage = imagecreatefromstring($theRawImage);
imagejpeg($theRawImage, $theDirectoryTwo);
```

Running that would either result in a perfect jpeg everytime unless someone was trying to name a text file to like "anImage.jpg", the above bit would result in just a black image. Just have to make sue that the GD libraries are installed.

Of corse there's always the dreaded Chmod 777 security risk, as long as only uploaded files are going in there, you should be fine, haven't had any issues with that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo with "extension" and "extensions". If fixed, check your file with `is_uploaded_file`.

`in_array($extension, $allowExts)` must be `in_array($extensions, $allowExts)` or name `$extensions` to `$extension`.

You must use element 1 like `$extension[1]`

Comment: I just tried making the change, still Invalid. The image will upload to 100% then give me the error

Comment: yea sorry my bad, wait, you must use $extension[1] for the split extension. Uhm no, sorry didnt see `end()`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a little lost with your comment, use $extension[1] or don't??

Comment: The use of `end()` is fine. `$extension[1]` is a bad idea, do not use it. @Giovatto if you show the result of `print_r($_FILES);` the problem will become obvious.

Comment: Invalid FileArray ( [file] => Array ( [name] => url.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /tmp/phps40kxq [error] => 0 [size] => 1957339 ) )

Comment: That was the error I received but I'm not sure what to adjust

Comment: @MrCode I'm still not seeing the issue, I pasted my new code above

Comment: Did you get the same error with `url.png`? Its size is close to the max size limit of 2000000. Also check your error log for any warnings/errors.

Comment: Yes, let me attempt a smaller image

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in ../uploader/upload.php on line 30

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpKOiEu8' to 'images/' in ../uploader/upload.php on line 30
Stored in: images/

Answer (score 0):

From the comments I can see that you've been uploading files that are above the size limit. The actual file size can vary slightly across operating systems so be sure to use a big enough limit.

It might be worth creating a file validation function that does each individual check (type, size, extension) and have it return a meaningful error that is more granular such as invalid extension, invalid type etc. This will make it easier to debug in future.

Comment: I have the size limit raised but its still giving me the same Warning, I've just updated the second part once more.

Comment: is `images` on the same level as `uploader.php`?